# Group Data using two columns and merge the third column into a single row

Tags: r

I have the data in this form

[image]

I want this as Ouput using R

[image]

Comment: Please show an example using `dput`

Comment: Perhaps you need `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(subject, center) %>% summarise(rollno = paste(rollno, collapse="|")) %>% ungroup %>% mutate(subject = replace(subject, duplicated(subject), ""))`

Answer (score 1):

We can do this in `dplyr`.  After grouping by 'subject', 'center', we `paste` the 'rollno' by `collapse`ing with `|` in `summarise` and `replace` the `duplicated` 'subject' with blank (`''`)

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(subject, center) %>%
  summarise(rollno = paste(rollno, collapse="|")) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(subject = replace(subject, duplicated(subject), ""))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  subject center rollno     
#  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>      
#1 "100"     2500 700|701|702
#2 ""        2501 703        
#3 "101"     2500 701        
#4 ""        2501 705        
#5 "102"     2500 707        
#6 ""        2502 701|700
```

---

Or in `base R` with `aggregate/replace/transform`

```
transform(aggregate(rollno ~ ., df1, paste, collapse='|'), 
       subject = replace(subject, duplicated(subject), ""))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(subject = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 101, 101, 102, 
102, 102), center = c(2500, 2500, 2500, 2501, 2500, 2501, 2502, 
2500, 2502), rollno = c(700, 701, 702, 703, 701, 705, 701, 707, 
700)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try the base R code below using `aggregate` + `replace`

```
x <- aggregate(roll.no ~ ., df, FUN = function(v) paste0(v,collapse = "|")) 
dfout <- within(x[order(x$subject,x$center),], 
                subject <-replace(subject,duplicated(subject),""))
```

such that

```
> dfout
  subject center     roll.no
1     100   2500 700|701|702
4           2501         703
2     101   2500         701
5           2501         705
3     102   2500         707
6           2502     701|700
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(subject = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 101, 101, 102, 
102, 102), center = c(2500, 2500, 2500, 2501, 2500, 2501, 2502, 
2500, 2502), roll.no = c(700, 701, 702, 703, 701, 705, 701, 707, 
700)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```